# How to filter search within a set of letters in search bar so that each letter typed will reduce the results in objective -c

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

i have implemented a search bar that searching trough an array of countries(presented in a picker view), the problem is that the user need to type the full country name that it will find it and i want him to be able to type even one letter and it will show the first country that starts with that letter and if types another than it sorts even further etc etc. 
Anyone have any ideas??

```
for(int x = 0; x < countryTable.count; x++){

    NSString *countryName = [[countryTable objectAtIndex:x]objectForKey:@"name"];

    if([searchedStr isEqualToString:countryName.lowercaseString]){

        [self.picker selectRow:i inComponent:0 animated:YES];

        flag.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[countryTable objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"flag"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code for the `UISearchBarDelegate` methods you've implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a method on NSArray called `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` and a method on NSString called `hasPrefix:`.  Together they do what you need...

```
NSString *userInput = //... user input as lowercase string.  don't call this countryName, its confusing
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id element, NSDictionary *bind) {
    NSString countryName = [[element objectForKey:@"name"] lowercaseString];
    return [countryName hasPrefix:userInput];
}];
NSArray *filteredCountries = [countryTable filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on iOS 8 or OS X Yosemite, you can do:

```
NSString *country = countryName.lowercaseString; //"england"
NSString *needle = @"engl"; 
if (![country containsString:needle]) {
    NSLog(@"Country string does not contain part (or whole) of searched country");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Found the country!");
}
```

Else, if on versions below iOS 8:

```
NSString *country = countryName.lowercaseString; //"england"
NSString *needle = @"engl"; 
if ([country rangeOfString:needle].location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"Country string does not contain part (or whole) of searched country");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Found the country!");
}
```

Lastly, just iterate through all possible countries and apply this to them all. There might exist more robust solutions out there (like danh's solution with some smaller modifications), but this is by far the easiest to start with.